# How to run APT command in Kotlin using exec?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing application for Android using Kotlin language.

Currently I try to execute the command using exec method:
**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget http://example.com/file/to/path")**

And get the error:
**/system/bin/sh: wget: not found**

When I try to install wget on my Android using apt-get on my android device I also get error something like:

**/system/bin/sh: apt-get: not found**

**My question is:**

What I must do to run wget, apt-get and other linux command from Runtime.getRuntime().exec() inside my android app which I develop on Kotlin?
I know that is real because Termux terminal android app can do it (http://termux.com).

***P.S: solution must work without root (I think that is real also because Termux working without root on my phone).***

Best Regards,
Sergei.

Comment: Termux has actually emulated those, and without root you cannot add anything to /usr/bin as they are not permissible. Termux store binaries in its allocated storage and emulate their functionalities using android bundles or libraries. There's no real debian commands in android.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks)
So my solution is: develop emulator something like Termux for first.